# Call method taking unit type as parameter from JavaScript

Tags: michelson, truffle

I have a Truffle instance of the contract and I call the method like this

```
contract_instance.method();
```

This gives me this error message:

```
method Received 0 arguments while expecting on of the follow signatures ([["unit"]])
```

How do I express the `Unit` value in JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You express the `Unit` in JavaScript by calling the method like this

```
contract_instance.method([["unit"]]);
```